# How to make prices in different color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to display prices followed by a $ sign in a different color in the heading. I don't want to display all numbers in different color - just where $ sign appears and the digits after that. There could be up to two numbers after the decimal point in some cases e.g. where price is $12.50

I have access to both HTML and CSS on the server.

Please see below code that is used to display heading. Please let me know how I change this code.

`<a href="{$story_url}" rel="nofollow">{$title_short}</a>`

Thanks for your help in advance in solving this.

Example:

[image]

Comment: http://www.ozbargain.com.au/node/50312 - This is an example. See $88 is highlighted in red. It is Drupal CMS.

Comment: now I'm curious. If you want only the $price to be highlighted, then you need to put a `<span>` or similar around it when it gets rendered. You can't just take a part of some text out using javascript without some sort of indicator, and since the prices are generic you can't tell the javascript to pick out specific parts of the string.

Comment: Somehow the example page does it.

Comment: That's because it has an <em> tag with a class around the price.

Comment: It depends on how the string are rendered. You have access to the HTML pages, look through that to see if the string gets rendered there, elsewise you'll have to look in the codebehind files (if you have access to those)

Answer (score 5):

If you have access to the HTML, you can simply wrap all the prices in a span tag and assign some class to them. Then just use CSS to set the color:

`<span class="price">$12.34</span>`

Answer (score 2):

Why not just add a span like:

css:

```
span.money{
    color: red;
}
```

html:

```
$<span class="money">12.50</span>
```

Comment: Thanks .. since it is part of a CMS, heading is generated dynamically so I can't do it this way.

Comment: But you said you have access to the CSS file? In that case, simply add the rule to it.

Comment: Even if it is part of a CMS that is generated, there will be editable template files which you can make these changes.

Comment: Hi, This is the code to display the heading. <a href="{$story_url}" rel="nofollow">{$title_short}</a> How do I modify it?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, this should do the trick if you use jQuery

```
$('element:contains("$")').css('color', 'whatever color you'd like');
```

Example

```
$('table th:contains("$")').css('color', 'yellow');
```

Comment: This will fail on this example `<p>This cost $5.</p>` and `$('p:contains("$")').css('color','yellow');`. It will color everything enclosed in `<p></p>`

Comment: @ace So I found out. I posted this before he posted the example :)

Comment: Yes, I think it's better off to add the `<span>` elements while creating the page rather than loading it changing the colors after with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming , you the values are in a

tag (or any selectable node) , you can replace them back with a regex . Something like

```
$('p:contains("$")').html(function(i,html){
    return html.replace(/(\$\d+(\.\d+)?)/g,function($1){
    return '<em class="money">'+$1+'</em>';
    });
});
```

Here's a quick demo .

http://jsfiddle.net/ngcBg/

Comment: I have added the CSS and the tags. Where do I exactly add the javascript?

Comment: If you use jquery , the code as such added to the script section should work .   If not , well , in document.onload , select all <p> tags , check if their innerHTML contains a $ char , if yes , replace it as in the fiddle .